# Variable for Tkinter cannot be set correctly when call by another python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a starter for python. I want to create a module for another python. Below is a simple example. I could get correct answer when execute temp3c.py. But, when I call tpmp3c from temp.py, there's no any item on Listbox. Looks like the variable "a" can be set correctly. But, it does not pass to listvariable for Listbox. Could someone give me a suggestion for this? Thanks.

temp3.py

```
import tkinter as tk    

class temp3c():
    def fun1():
        TK3=tk.Tk()
        TK3.title("Teset File")
        TK3.geometry('200x300')
        tk.Label(TK3, text="Temp3：").pack()
        ls=['aa','bb','cc','dd']
        a=tk.StringVar()
        a.set(ls)
        print('t:',a.get())
        A=tk.Listbox(TK3, listvariable=a)
        A.pack()                        
        TK3.mainloop()
#A1=temp3c
#A1.fun1()
```

temp.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from temp3 import temp3c

TK=tk.Tk()
TK.title("Teset File")
TK.geometry('250x350')

def TC():
    B=temp3c
    B.fun1()

nbtb=tk.Button(TK, text='testing', command=TC)
nbtb.pack()

TK.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should probably read a little bit on classes and OOP before trying to make a GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original Answer

I'm not sure that I understand the question fully, but to me it looks like you want the elements from `ls` inside of `A`. Firstly, the `Listbox` class doesn't get given a list, instead you have to manually set each item that you want inside the `Listbox`. You can add an object by using `Listbox.insert(index, element)`.

Because an index number is needed, a good way to do this in your case (as you are using a list) is to use `enumerate()`

```
ls = ['aa','bb','cc','dd']

for i, item in enumerate(ls):
    A.insert(i, item)
```

This will put them all into separate indexes in `A`. Sorry if this isn't the answer you are looking for, hope it helps anyway!

---

### In regard to your comment

If you want to be able to pass the `temp3c` class a list to display everytime, you can do that, in my new example I've passed it as an argument in the `fun` function.

```
#temp3.py

class temp3c:
    def fun1(items):
        TK3=tk.Tk()
        TK3.title("Teset File")
        TK3.geometry('200x300')
        tk.Label(TK3, text="Temp3：").pack()

        A = tk.Listbox(TK3)
        A.pack()

        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            A.insert(i, item)

        TK3.mainloop()
```

To do this, you need a way to pass the function a list. You can hard code this, or use a simple user interface like this one.

```
#temp.py

import tkinter as tk
from temp3 import temp3c

TK=tk.Tk()
TK.title("Teset File")
TK.geometry('250x350')

values = []

def TC():
    B=temp3c
    B.fun1(values)

def add_value(event=None):
    values.append(entry.get())
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def reset(event=None):
    for i in range(len(values)-1, -1, -1):
        values.pop(i)

tk.Label(TK, text='Values to add')
entry = tk.Entry(TK)
entry.pack()
add = tk.Button(TK, text='Add Value', command=add_value)
add.pack()
delete = tk.Button(TK, text='Delete Values', command=reset)
delete.pack()

nbtb=tk.Button(TK, text='testing', command=TC)
nbtb.pack(pady=20)

TK.mainloop()
```

Comment: The insert is work for me. Thanks for your help! I am not sure why the variable cannot be passed when call function. Listbox with variable(list) is workable when execute by temp3.py only. .

Comment: @chen i've updated my answer so that you don't need to hard-code a list, with the new example you can let the user enter their own items, and delete them if they aren't happy with them. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Crawley "the Listbox class doesn't get given a list" It does as you can see by running the first piece of code alone (uncomment the commented-out lines).

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution for this.

Just assign the tk object to the string variable and issue solved.

a=tk.StringVar(TK3)

Comment: Use only one instance of `Tk` and you won't have a problem to solve.